# integrals: rotating a curve about curve?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image: half circles]

Can we rotate the half circle  $y=25-x^2$  about half circle $y=16-x^2$ 
or opposite? Or is there any situation that a curve can be rotated about a curve?$$$$

Comment: Unclear question

Comment: which part is unclear it is a question such that rotate the curve about y-axis but instead of y axis it is curve

Comment: @Don I think the question is clear. I think perhaps you need some coffee to wake up?

Answer (score 1):

The  rotation of a curve requires a specified *axis of rotation* about which the points on the curve rotate, and an *axis of rotation* is by definition, a line.

The fact that any axis of rotation is necessarily a line is due to how we define "rotational motion." See [rotation about a fixed axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_rotation) for a bit more of an elaboration. For example:

> "Purely rotational motion occurs if every particle in the body [or on the curve] moves in a circle about a single line. This line is called the axis of rotation." (Brackets mine.]

Comment: thanks but why it should be a line is there a any rule such that or where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the logical way is to extend the notion of what happens when we rotate about the line, say, $L$. Each point of the curve is being rotated around its projection onto the line $L$ and the radius of the rotation becomes the distance of the point to $L$.

There is nothing in this definition that assumes $L$ is a line. If we let $L$ be an upper half-circle around the origin with radius $4$, rotating a half circle of radius $5$ around it creates a half-circle with radius $3$ "on the other side" and each point rotates with the radial projection from radius 5, to 4, to 3 being the diameter of the rotation.

Comment: shouldn't it creates a 3 dimensional shape assuming that we rotate it 360 degree

Comment: and I think it won't look like a circle but I can't think further